# Can I write a DNS Zone file with $TTL using dnspython?

Tags: python, dns, dnspython

I use `dns.zone.Zone` from dnspython to represent DNS zones, and when I use the `to_text()` method, I get a zone that looks like this:

```
@ 86400 IN SOA dns0.noris.net. hostmaster.noris.net. 1234 86400 1800 2419200 600
@ 86400 IN A 185.199.108.153
@ 86400 IN A 185.199.109.153
@ 86400 IN A 185.199.110.153
@ 86400 IN A 185.199.111.153
```

Is there any way to get the output to use a BIND-style default TTL, instead of one TTL per record, like this?

```
$TTL 86400
@ IN SOA dns0.noris.net. hostmaster.noris.net. 1234 86400 1800 2419200 600
@ IN A 185.199.108.153
@ IN A 185.199.109.153
@ IN A 185.199.110.153
@ IN A 185.199.111.153
```

(background: I want to minimize diffs when the default zone TTL changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dnspython` library, as of `v2.1.0rc1` (the latest version as of November, 9, 2020), doesn't support this type of a zone style *per se*.
Going down your stack trace for the `to_text()` call:

1. [`dns/zone.py#622:`](https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/blob/10bf69abb43ded230df6fbe555c590c629a8d97e/dns/zone.py#L622) `to_text()`
2. [`dns/zone.py#586:`](https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/blob/10bf69abb43ded230df6fbe555c590c629a8d97e/dns/zone.py#L586) `to_file()`
3. [`dns/node.py#53:`](https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/blob/10bf69abb43ded230df6fbe555c590c629a8d97e/dns/node.py#L53) `to_text()`
4. [`dns/rdataset.py#233:`](https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/blob/10bf69abb43ded230df6fbe555c590c629a8d97e/dns/rdataset.py#L233) `to_text()`

— this is where the actual formatting is being done:

```
for rd in self:
    extra = ''
    if want_comments:
        if rd.rdcomment:
            extra = f' ;{rd.rdcomment}'
        s.write('%s%s%d %s %s %s%s\n' %
                (ntext, pad, self.ttl, dns.rdataclass.to_text(rdclass),
                 dns.rdatatype.to_text(self.rdtype),
                 rd.to_text(origin=origin, relativize=relativize,
                            **kw),
                 extra))
```

So, as you can see, `self.ttl` is included into the `rdataset` text output invariably.

What you can do though is iterate over the zone, creating a zone file of your preferred style yourself — or make changes directly to the `to_text()` output which is a [standardized zone description](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) and thus is stable enough to be processed automatically. Quick example of how that could look:

```
zone_lines = ['$TTL %s' % zone['@'].rdatasets[0].ttl]
for rdat in zone.to_text().decode('ascii').strip().split('\n'):
    rdat_params = rdat.split(' ')
    rdat_params.pop(1)
    zone_lines.append(' '.join(rdat_params))

zone_text = '\n'.join(zone_lines)
```

You can also create a feature request for the `dnspython` project [on Github](https://github.com/rthalley/dnspython/issues). The author would then consider your feature request, they have been quite responsive recently.